# WCF - How can I get a reference to the incoming message string in my service implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Based on the processing of the incoming request I have to store the original (unserialized) message as string to a database.

So far I implemented a `DispatchMessageInspector` and a `ServiceBehavior` that I used to decorate my service implementation. My `DispatchMessageInspector` has a property to which I store the message string. My service implementation includes some business rules that check the request and if this check fails I'd like to store the original message.

How can I achieve to access the message string property of my `DispatchMessageInspector` from the service implementation in an elegant way?

Comment: seems like you can see the [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534084/wcf-dispatchmessageinspector-process-and-make-available-to-operation) here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a Message Property containing the raw message in a form you like. Then in your service, you can access them through `OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties["RawMessage"]`.

Comment: Basically that was the idea, the related post has some sample code that can be applied right away, but the message properties are just what I need.